# How do you change the log level of an AzurePowerShell@5 task in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have a couple AzurePowerShell@5 tasks running in my Azure DevOps pipeline and they always output VERBOSE level logging which makes the output logs from these tasks largely useless.

I have not been able to find anything in the [documentation for the AzurePowerShell@5 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines) about log level, and all I have found in the general documentation is that you can enable VERBOSE logging by checking the "Enable system diagnostics" checkbox which is not checked for the jobs I am running.

So how can I change the log level of these tasks so that they are not flooding the logs?